# A database query for each object in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-database

I have a model Photos with a ForeignKey to the model User.

If I print a photo objects fields in a template, e.g.

```
<img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="{{ object.caption }}">
```

there will be 1 query, but if I print information about the user, e.g.

```
{{ object.caption }} by {{ object.user.first_name }}
```

there will be 2 queries. So in a ListView with 40 objects, there will be more than 40 queries to get the informations about the user. Is this right? To me it seems stupid, but I don't know if it is possible to get the same stuff done while avoiding so many database queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)